# Access parent scope in angular directive with template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I woud like to reuse a form to edit one type of property. I have a list of editors:

```js
ModelerControllers.controller('ModelController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$q',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $q) {
        ...
        $scope.mappingTypes = [
            {"name": "mixpanel", "label": "Mixpanel"},
            {"name": "mongo", "label": "Mongo"},
            {"name": "slicer", "label": "Slicer"},
            {"name": "sql", "label": "SQL"}, 
            {"name": "", "label": "Other"}
        ];
        ...
    }
]);
```

Then I have a directive:

```
CubesModelerApp.directive("mappingEditor", function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/mapping.html',
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            content: "=ngModel",
            mappingTypes: "@mappingTypes"
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.mappingTypes = $scope.$parent.mappingTypes;
        }
    }
});
```

Used as:

```
<div mapping-editor ng-model='content.mapping'></div>
```

With template content (relevant chunk):

```
<!-- language: html -->

...
<select class="form-control"
        ng-change="mappingTypeChanged(storeType)"
        ng-model="storeType"
        ng-options="f.name as f.label for f in mappingTypes">
</select>
...
```

This yields empty list – as if the `mappingTypes` was empty.

The `conent` from `ngModel` is bound correctly.

How do I access kind-of-global (from one of the parent scopes) enumeration in a directive template? Or is there any other way to achieve this, such as defining the list differently instead of app $scope variable?

EDIT: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stiivi/4ZZbs/).

Comment: A fiddle tends to result in more/quicker/better answers...

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Stiivi/4ZZbs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were a couple of issues with your code:

---

**1.**
According to **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object)** regarding the isolated scope of custom directives:

> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property **of name defined via the value of the attr attribute**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

This means that you need to reference an attribute whose value is the name of the parent scope property you want to share. E.g.:

```
...
<editor ng-model="content" my-items="items"></editor>

...
scope: {
    ...
    items: '=myItems'
},
```

Alternatively, you could do the binding in the directive;s `link` function:

```
...
<editor ng-model="content"></editor>

...
scope: {
    content: 'ngModel'
    // nothing `items` related here
},

...
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.items = scope.$parent.items;
}
```

---

**2.**
According to **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)** regarding the `select` element, the `ng-model` attribute is mandatory. You have to add it into your template string:

```
...
template:
    ...
    '<select ng-model="selectedItem"...
```

---

**3.**
According to **[the same docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect#usage_parameters)** regarding the `select` element, the `ng-options` attribute's value must have one of the specified forms, which you fail to provide (see the docs for moe info on the allowed forms). For the simple case at hand, the template string could be modified like this:

```
...ng-options="item for item in items"...
               \______/
                   |_____(you need to have a label)
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/ncwL8/)**.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have it without `my-items="items"`? This is redundant as it will be the same across the whole application.

Comment: Alternatively, you can bind the isolated scope's `items` property with its parent scope's `items` property in the `link` function: `link:function(scope,element,attrs){scope.items=scope.$parent.items;}`

Comment: That seem to solve my problem after removing all required $parent's properties from `scope: {...}`. See my original post, which has both `scope:{mappingTypes: ...}` and `$scope.mappingTypes = $scope.$parent.mappingTypes` – there should be only one of the two. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the argument `mapping-types` something like this

```
<div mapping-editor mapping-types='storeTypes' ng-model='content.mapping'></div>
```

If you set scope object in the directive, that means that this scope is isolated, and I'm not sure that you are able toe reach the parent scope. from the $parent object.

Comment: The `$scope.mappingTypes = $scope.$parent.mappingTypes;` works – according to the JS debugger the attribute is set correctly from the `$parent` in the `link` function. It is just empty in the template. I would like to avoid to require another property as it would be redundant – it is the same within the whole application. Doesn't the `link()` prepare the scope for the template?

Comment: @Stiivi, to be sure that the mappingTypes collection has been populated, add following html after select, `<div ng-repeat='f in mappingTypes' ng-bind='f.name' />`, if it is ok, try leave following, `<select ng-options="f.name for f in mappingTypes" ng-model="option"></select>`. If it works, change model and add attributes one by one to find out where is the problem.

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stiivi/4ZZbs/) which is showing the issue I am having.

Comment: Ok, couple things should be changed in your fiddle. 1. pass items variable to editor `<editor ng-model="content" items="items"></editor>`. 2. declare `items` variable in the following way in the directive `items: '='`. 3. you need a model and a label for the select tag `<select class="form-control" ng-model="selecteditem" ng-options="item for item in items">`. And it works!